# Does every f.g. group have a minimal presentation?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Call a group presentation $\langle X \,\|\,R \rangle$ *minimal* if no relator from $R$ is a consequence of the remaining relators, i.e., no $r \in R$ belongs to the normal closure of $R\setminus \{r\}$ in the free group $F(X)$.

**Question:** Does every finitely generated group have a minimal presentation (with $X$ finite)?

*Remark:* evidently every finite presentation $\langle X \,\|\,R \rangle$ has a minimal sub-presentation $\langle X \,\|\,R' \rangle$ (where $R' \subseteq R$ has the same normal closure in $F(X)$ as $R$), so the question really concerns infinitely presented groups.

It is possible to construct infinite presentations which do not have minimal sub-presentations. Indeed, let $F=F(a,b)$ be the free group on $\{a,b\}$. One can choose "sufficiently independent" elements $w_1,w_2,\dots \in F$ so that the presentation $$\langle a,b \,\|\, w_i^2,w^2_{i+1}w_i, ~i \in \mathbb{N} \rangle$$ has no minimal sub-presentation. Here $R$ consists of the elements  $w_1^2,w_2^2,\dots$, and $w_2^2w_1,w_3^2w_2,\dots$.

However, the above group also has the presentation $\langle a,b \,\|\,w_1,w_2,\dots \rangle$, which may be minimal.

Comment: Look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0271.  I'm sure @YCor can say more.

Comment: Dear Ashot, the answer is negative: combine Theorem. 3.5 and Remark 5.3 of the paper cited by Benjamin Steinberg. A counter-example is given by the nilpotent-by-Abelian group $B$ of Equation (3.2).

Comment: Dear Benjamin: many thanks for providing the reference, it is spot on!

Comment: Dear Luc: nice paper! I should have read it before asking!

Comment: @AshotMinasyan, I believe that paper was one of the first talks I heard by YCor, and so I remembered it right away.

Comment: @LucGuyot Why not make that an answer?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow This is an answer now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is **no**.

In order to see this, you may combine Theorem 3.9 and Remark 5.3 of [1]. A counter-example is given by the nilpotent-by-Abelian group $B$ of Equation (3.2). Further examples are provided by Remark 5.15.

---

[1] R. Bieri, Y. de Cornulier, L. Guyot and R. Strebel, ["Infinite presentability of groups and condensation"](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3249690), 2014.